# Is the phrase "Con pelos y señales" used to describe something concrete, or just to how a story is told?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

Can anyone tell me if the phrase "Con pelos y señales" can be used to describe something like 'I painted the mural with great detail' in this way?

> Lo pinté con pelos y señales.

Or it is only used in the context of telling a story, as in this example?

> Lo conté con pelos y señales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression "con pelos y señales" is normally used only with verbs of speech like *contar*, *describir*, *explicar* or *mostrar*.

Searching the Internet for good examples of "pintar con pelos y señales", I have found that it can be used when "pintar" is used meaning "to depict":

> Pintar con pelos y señales: dar una descripción detallada. X «El fidedigno padre Valdecebro, | Que en discurrir historias de animales | Se calentó el cerebro, | Pintándolos con pelos y señales.» T. Iriarte, Poes. (Cl. C. 136. 12). ([Source](http://habilis.udg.edu/%7Einfo/webs/Corpus%20i%20diccionaris/R%20J%20Cuervo,%20Diccionario%20de%20construcci%C3%B3n%20y%20r%C3%A9gimen%20de%20la%20lengua%20castellana/pintar.htm))

"Dibujar con pelos y señales" sounds a little better to me than "pintar con pelos y señales" when referring to a graphic representation.

Comment: I think I've never heard this expression with verbs other than *describir* and *explicar*, suggesting detail. I believe the idea is that you're describing the key identifying features of someone (the hair and "signs" like tatoos, scars and so on).